# Stretch a sprite between two points during runtime in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a `UnityEngine.Sprite` and need it to be stretched between two points.

How can I achieve this at runtime using Unity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Put the sprite in the middle of the two points.

**If you want a runtime stretching effect**

2. Change the sprites scale until the bounds match those of the points. You can use [Lerp](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html) to help achieve this affect over a specified period of time.

**If you want it to fill the space instantly**

2. Calculate how much you need to scale by and scale by that amount

---

**Calculating scale**

```
scale = targetSize / realSize;
```

So, given a space of 1000 x 400 pixels that you wish to fill with an 800 x 600 image...

```
scale.x = 1000 / 800;
scale.y = 400 / 600;
```

Comment: How to calculate scale

Comment: What is Target Size and realSize?

Comment: @user3506498 added example

Comment: I have 2 Points initial and final and a sprite now what should I do

Comment: That's already in the answer, please at least try to work things out first.

Comment: How do I get the pixels Width and Height

Comment: As I said before, please try to work things out yourself first. If you spend a few minutes googling that you'll find an answer very easily.

Comment: Still unable to get the effect I want but thanks for baring me I thought of a better effect

Comment: You can use Lerp with the target and current to get this effect. You should try and get this working for your learnings sake if nothing else.

Comment: Its not the effect I want but sprites to be placed exactly where I want them to be, but they are distant even after placing them in middle of two points rotating them accordingly and scaling them by your method. The problem is with scaling though